# Nuget trying to install a ton of dependencies on certain packages

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, nuget, visual-studio-2017

I am running Visual Studio 2017 with all of my projects in my solution running.NET 4.6.2. My solution has a mix of MVC projects and shared class libraries. On certain nuget packages that have added support for .NET Core, when I go to update to the latest version it wants me to install 20+ additional packages relating to .NET Core and .NET Standard. I have been avoiding installing these newer versions because it seems like I should not need all of these packages. I only seem to have this issue on 4 or 5 packages.

Any solutions?

[image: Nuget Package Update Dialog]

Comment: Look at the top two, but specifically System.Net.Http.4.0.0. -> 4.3.0. Notice how the other dependencies all share the same 4.3.0 version? They need to be updated as well to reflect the System.Net.Http.4.0.0 upgrade. This is completely normal.

Comment: In fact, go ahead and update, then try to uninstall any of the dependencies you believe are unnecessary. I'd bet, you'll get an error about it being a required package for `System.Net.Http.4.3.0`.

Comment: @JoeyZero, Obviously, NuGet try to install 20+ dependencies relating to .NET Core and .NET Standard to your projects, so you should check your target Framework for your project, is it .NET core or .NET Standard.? If confirm your target framework is . Net framework, please share the package`s id which have this issue when you updating, so that I could reproduce this issue.

Comment: As stated in the question, .NET Framework 4.6.2

Comment: I created a brand new MVC project (only project in the solution) targeting .NET Framework 4.6.2 and then tried to install some of these packages with the same results.
Packages I have noticed:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Mandrill/3.1.0/

https://www.nuget.org/packages/MailChimp.Net.V3/3.0.0/

https://www.nuget.org/packages/MiniProfiler/4.0.0-alpha9-00206

I found out the MailChimp.NET.V3 package has a fix in the alpha package so it seems like it is probably issues with how people are packaging in nuget.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it seems like it is probably issues with how people are packaging in nuget.

Yes, you are right. This issue is related to the author who packing the NuGet package. I have ever reported the [similar issue](https://github.com/OData/odata.net/issues/953) on GitHub.

For the package `MailChimp.Net.V3`, there is a reported issue about installing wrong dependencies: [Tons of new dependencies when updating to v3 on .net 4.6.2](https://github.com/brandonseydel/MailChimp.Net/issues/270). This issue has been fixed at the version `3.1.1-alpha`.

The package of `Mandrill`, this package has a dependency `NETStandard.Library (>= 1.6.1)`, so it is correct to install tons of .NET shandard dependencies.

The package of `MiniProfiler`, which including a dependency of `MiniProfiler.Shared (>= 4.0.0-alpha9-00206)`. This latest version of dependency package should be incorrect, it will install tons of .NET shandard dependencies. To resolve this issue, please install the previous version: `MiniProfiler 4.0.0-alpha9-00202`:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Leo, I did see the alpha version of Mailchimp.Net.V3 so I will just wait to upgrade from 2.1 until they release the new final version.

I contacted Nick Craver about the issue with MiniProfiler and he is looking into it.

Not sure what I should do about the Mandrill package..